# Difference between cascade remove and explicit remove

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

Suppose we have 2 entity classes `Employee` and `Address` and `Address` class is referenced in the `Employee` class:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    :
  @OneToOne
  private Address address;
    :
}
```

If we use explicit `remove`:

```
Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1);

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(employee);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I know it will remove `employee` instance from the `Employee` table, but does it also remove the referenced `address` instance from the `Address` table? Or should we explicitly use `remove` on that `address` instance to remove it from the `Address`table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of @OneToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html), by default no operations are cascaded. That means in your case the address is not removed when you remove the employee.

**See also** :  [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)